# does npm node-cache value can be set in one file and access in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, mern

i am working on a nodejs app where i have to maintain an api token for 24hr and then refersh it, currently i am writing that token on json file in every update and it's not good for security, then i came to know  about npm node-cache module but it seems it's value cannot be accessed in whole project(like setting in one file and accessing in another), is this how it works or m i missing something?

eg file 1

```
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");

const myCache = new NodeCache();

myCache.set("token", {token: "123", expirein: 123});

const test2 = require("./test2.js");

console.log(test2);
```

eg file 2 (test2.js)

```
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");

const myCache = new NodeCachae();

let c = myCache.get("token");
module.exports = c;
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't create a new cache in each file. Create one global cache and use it everywhere.

`cache.js`

```
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");

module.exports = new NodeCache();
```

`index.js`

```
const myCache = require("./cache");

myCache.set("token", {token: "123", expirein: 123});

const test2 = require("./test2.js");

console.log(test2);
```

`test2.js`

```
const myCache = require("./cache");

let c = myCache.get("token");
module.exports = c;
```